# задача на симетричное отображений

Tags: c++

В общем. Есть [задача](https://imcs.dvfu.ru/cats/static/problem_text-cpid-2545514.html?sid=pSz5bEtkU4tIDbFtLwUG1LfOLldj6T)
Так же есть вот такой код размещения '*'
Число логически в голове крутится версия проще ( с помощью abs()) Но никак не могу продумать ее, чем повторение по 100 раз этого кода. Можно ли в один цикл уместить данную функцию?

```
   int delx = x - 1, dely = y - 1;    
   while (dely >= 0 && delx >= 0) {
        table[dely][delx] = '*';
        delx--;
        dely--;
    }
    delx = x - 1, dely = y + 1;
    while (dely < n && delx >= 0) {
        table[dely][delx] = '*';
        delx--;
        dely++;
    }
    delx = x + 1, dely = y - 1;
    while (dely >= 0 && delx < n) {
        table[dely][delx] = '*';
        delx++;
        dely--;
    }
    delx = x + 1, dely = y + 1;
    while (dely < n && delx < n) {
        table[dely][delx] = '*';
        delx++;
        dely++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Составьте функцию, которая принимает координаты клетки (i, j) и слонана (X, Y) и возвращает тип клетки. А дальше просто для каждой клетки вызовите эту функцию